# Android Offline and online Apps using cache & Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, browser-cache, offline-caching

my experience with cache in Android using Phonegap .

```
  1.  I want to create one app which should work online as well as offline. 
  2.  If internet connectivity is there it should use otherwise use the history.
```

Now it working with the online ..but i need to work my app in off line too. for the checking network connection :

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.network.isReachable("phonegap.com", reachableCallback, {});
    navigator.notification.alert("Server Is Ready");


 }

       // Check network status
 //
 function reachableCallback(reachability) {
     // There is no consistency on the format of reachability
     var networkState = reachability.code || reachability;
     var states = {};
     states[NetworkStatus.NOT_REACHABLE]  = 'No network connection';
     states[NetworkStatus.REACHABLE_VIA_CARRIER_DATA_NETWORK] = 'Carrier data connection';
     states[NetworkStatus.REACHABLE_VIA_WIFI_NETWORK] = 'WiFi connection';

     alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
  }
```

Can any one help me to access my my app while there is no any nwtwork connection(offline)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:
`<html manifest="cache.manifest">` instead of `<html>`.

And create a new file in the same directory named `cache.manifest`.

The contents of that file should look like this

CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
blabla.png

Comment: ok. but i didnt clear this sentence:"The contents of that file should look like this: CACHE MANIFEST ## Required First Line index.html blabla.png"

Comment: The contents of `cache.manifest` must be in the format specified. The first like must be `CACHE MANUFEST`, and the other lines need to be the names of the files you would like to cache.

Comment: The new lines somehow go through it should be like this: `CACHE MANIFEST \newline\ file.html \new line\ etc.html`

Comment: Thank you..Refer this too: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#offline