# PhoneGap Offline Caching json data

Tags: html, cordova, offline-caching, offlineapps

I'm building a Phonegap application and i'm planning to set it to work in both Offline and Online mode, the idea is to get JSON Data from a PHP server side script and show it in the application, these data contains text, images so my question is is there anyway to set a dynamic cache manifest or any other way in a way that the user can see the already loaded data when he's offline, like caching the json result itself or anything else you can help me with

thanks

Comment: please do not add.extra questions to your posts like this.

Comment: check out this if users still looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891537/android-offline-and-online-apps-using-cache-phonegap

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "work in both Offline and Online mode"? Are the users able to only see the user created data or can they modify it too? Is it correct to use a Manifest to control caching of user created data? I would have thought you should only really use it for caching the application templates and code. In any case I think you'll probably need something that you can exert more control over, something based perhaps using WebSQL, IndexedDb or LocalStorage.

I have been working on the modify-it-too question for many months and have a solution in the form of javascript(phonegap) <-> server synchronization that works somewhat like a version control system, with version numbers and conflict resolution. There's some pretty great docs and demo [on the GitHub page](https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncIt) and you can even see a presentation courtesy of [SkillsMatter / LondonAJAX](http://skillsmatter.com/podcast/ajax-ria/syncit-solving-offline-for-apps).. Currently there is only a JS/Node based server but I will probably do PHP based server because that's my day job If you look at the server code it's pretty easy to implement.

BTW I would use a different method to store the images, why not just download them and store them in a [File](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#File), I don't know the storage limits, but I bet that is the way that Phonegap will let you get away with most.

Comment: thanks but maybe you got me wrong in my application there's no users data, the application aims to get articles and categories from a remote joomla site, i want to do something like the Google+ or Facebook application where you can see the feeds you've already seen even if there's no connection and thanks again for the File  API in phone-gap you gave me more ideas