# Create an html offline application for android and ios ( at least )

Tags: html, offlineapps

I would like to create add an offline version of my website, so that it can be used by people who are not necessarily connected when using it ( I am thinking of gyms that are located in basements and do not offer a wi-fi connection ).

I did some research, but I couldn't find anything that specifically explains how to do what I need. I am beginning to think it just isn't possible...

If anybody can confirm that this is possible, and can think of a link to a tutorial for the following points, I would be extremely grateful.

- it should work both on Android and ios without being altered ( both required entries in web.xml I guess, or any solutions )
- it should create an clickable icon so that it can be launched like a native application ( not a link or button in the browser, such as Opera's speed dial ).
- possibly a brief example of code. I am just thinking something that I can use as a starting point. An alert message when clicking on a button would be enough...
- I tend to stay away from any frameworks as much as possible as a personal preference, but I am willing to give one a go if it's the only solution.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot, bro: extremely broad. It might be a better idea to petition the moderators to move this to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We're not a *write-my-code-for-me* service; show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @michaelb958 I have done nothing at all so far, hence my question on whether it was possible to do it or not. I am not sure what you mean by "show us what you've tried so far". I was asking for a link to a tutorial if anyone knew a good one. If you are asking me the list of all the different googled combinations of the words "html5 offline application android ios" and a few more I can't remember right now, I admit I didn't write them all down and I haven't got an answer to that...

Comment: @Dan Sorry to break this to you, but SO isn't somewhere to ask for links to tutorials.

Comment: @jrd1 - thanks, I wasn't aware of that. However, lemieuxster still managed to give me a good link to get started from, I will take it from there. I will ask them to move it.

Comment: @michaelb958 don't worry - somebody had already broken it to me a while ago in a very straightforward way, including a suggestion on where to move this thread to and whom I should contact to make it happen. Constructive criticism at its best! Thanks to everybody for the contribution.

Comment: I answered some portions of your question previously at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159152/phonegap-offline-caching-json-data/17161970#17161970

Comment: @Forbesmyester Thanks, I will have to use some ways to store data and I was only aware of local storage, I will take a look at the other ones you mentioned to see which one is the most appropriate

Comment: your comment on the answer solved my problem. too bad it does not stick out more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some resources that can get you started:

HTML5 Supports App Caching, and it works at least on iOS and I think more modern android phones as well. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

On iOS at least there are special meta-tags you can use in your html to make the page savable to the launch screen.

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">`

So you can look up how to best use those.

Those things should point you in the right direction, but keep in mind that anything stored for offline use needs to be small and efficient since there is usually a limit to the amount of data that can be stored offline. Also, some browsers require that the user grant permission before any data can be saved, but the request dialog is sometimes intimidating. (e.g. "This web page wants to save data on your computer without your knowledge, do you want to let it do that?")

Comment: Thanks @lemieuxster, definitely what I was looking for. Another one I found after posting the original question ( sometimes it does happen! ) is this: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-offlineweb/